# Deduplication based on non primary key field

Tags: marketing-cloud, sql

I have a data extension that has duplicate email address and it has a primary key field. I need to deduplicate the data extension based on the email address. The rows that are duplicate have same email address but different id value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this query to deduplicate using the email address:

```
SELECT
SubscriberKey,
Email

FROM
(SELECT DEST.SubscriberKey, DEST.Email, DEST.Creation_Date,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY DEST.Email ORDER BY DEST.Creation_Date DESC) 
        AS Row
    FROM YOUR_DE_NAME DEST 
 ) as s
 WHERE row=1
```

In this case, the query will return the record having the last creation date. You can add more columns to sort duplicate results..

Comment: Quickdraw McGraw over here. what was it, 6 minutes after being posted? Good job on a great answer though!

Comment: I need the primary key field as well

Comment: ^^ Thanks Gregory.. @swatimishra sorry I don't get you. Although, you can replace SubscriberKey by your Primary Key, or add your primary key in both parts of the query (as email and subscriberkey)..

Comment: Yes, I did that. It works fine. Thanks a lot!!! You have saved me today :)

Comment: Glad I can help. Don't forget mark it as accepted (click the checkmark icon), it will be easy for others to see it..